# Find the minimum inside for-comprehention?

Tags: scala

I have two lists contains GPS coordinates and I want to find the shortest distance between coordinates in these two lists. Right now I have iterated over  the lists and stored each distances in to another list like this:

```
val distanceList = for {
        c1 <- cordinatesList1
        c2 <- cordinatesList2
        distace = calculateDistances(c1, c2)

    } yield distance
```

Now I can get minimum from the `distanceList`, but Is there anyway to find the minimum inside the `for-comprehension` without storing all the distances ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can't be done inside the `for` but it can be done on the outside and if the evaluation is made lazily then intermediate results won't be saved.

```
(for {
  c1 <- cordinatesList1.toStream
  c2 <- cordinatesList2
} yield calculateDistances(c1,c2)).min
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a requirement to use for-comprehension?

You could do that easily with a foldLeft

```
val zipped = cordinatesList1.zip(cordinatesList2)
val minPossibleDistance = 0 //Assuming 0


zipped.foldLeft(minPossibleDistance) ((acc, elem) => if (acc < calculateDistances(elem._1, elem._2)) acc else calculateDistances(elem._1, elem._2))
```

Comment: `zip` doesn't do the same thing as the `for`, it makes far fewer comparisons, and folding from `0` you're not likely to get more than zero.